# Campo checkbox não é reconhecido marcado

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Eu tenho estes dois campos `checkbox`

```
 <label class="control-label col-md-3" style="text-align:left;">Tipo de Pedido</label>
 <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
      <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Produtos" onclick="checkProduto();"/>
      <label asp-for="Produtos" class="control-label"></label>
      <span asp-validation-for="Produtos" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
      <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Servico" onclick="checkServico();"/>
      <label asp-for="Servico" class="control-label"></label>
      <span asp-validation-for="Servico" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

Porém ele não reconhece que está marcado, quando eu faço um `console.log($("#Produtos")); console.log($("#Servico"));`
Ele sempre me retorna false, não consigo entender.

Comment: `#` procura pelo `id` e nenhum dos `inputs` tem um `id` definido

Comment: Saber se está marcado é feito com `$("#Produtos").is(":checked")`

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, obrigado @Isac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode passar o seletor atual para a função usando o `this`

```js
function checkProduto(chekProduto) {
  console.log($(chekProduto).is(':checked'))
}


function checkServico(chekServico) {
  console.log($(chekServico).is(':checked'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="control-label col-md-3" style="text-align:left;">Tipo de Pedido</label>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
  <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Produtos" onclick="checkProduto(this);" />
  <label asp-for="Produtos" class="control-label"></label>
  <span asp-validation-for="Produtos" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
  <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Servico" onclick="checkServico(this);" />
  <label asp-for="Servico" class="control-label"></label>
  <span asp-validation-for="Servico" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```